# Creating object in loop dynamically

Tags: c++, qt, c++11

I want to create many buttons in Qt within a loop.

In header file:

```
QVector<QPushButton> *btns;
```

In cpp file:

```
btns = new QVector<QPushButton>();
for(int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    btns->append(new QPushButton(QString::number(i),this));
}
```

I'm getting the error:

> cannot convert argument 1 from 'QPushButton *' to 'const QPushButton
>   &'

It's probably not hard to fix it, but I am not too good with pointers. Can you help me?

Comment: why do you use that ugly `new` all over the place ?

Comment: ***why do you use that ugly new all over the place ?*** Qt basically requires it. A parent will automatically free all of its children when the parent is freed. In the example `this` is the parent.

Comment: I almost never collect the buttons this way. Instead of putting them in a QVector<>, I just use findChildren<QPushButton>() when I need the list of buttons.

Comment: @drescherjm just because that feature is offered doesnt mean one has to use it. Wouldnt it be also fine to have a member `QVector<QPushButton*> btns;` and make use of RAII instead of some arcane qt garbage collection alike stuff ? ( i can understand that the vector has to contain pointers, but why allocating the vector itself dynamically??)

Comment: @drescherjm i didnt read the answer before. So yes it is just fine. There really is no good reason to have a `QVector*` when it can be a `QVector`, and it was actually just a typo

Comment: @tobi303 The vector itself I would not allocate dynamically. The `QPushButtons` I would however my previous comment explained that I would most likely not use a QVector for that anyways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in the header

```
QVector<QPushButton*>  btns;
```

in the source

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
   btns.append(new QPushButton(QString::number(i),this));
}
```

Comment: It is not necessary, but in some cases it is more safe to use `QVector< QPointer< QPushButton > >` because if button will be deleted outside, then array member will be nulled automatically.

Comment: you are right, but in general it depends which plans question author has for this container =)

Comment: Yep. That's why I wrote that it is not necessary :)

Answer (score 4):

You're trying to store the buttons by value. This is not yet possible in Qt containers, since they require the values to by copyable, and no Qt class deriving from `QObject` is copyable. The `QPushButton` can't be copied, and can't be stored by value in a Qt container.

What you need to do instead is either:

1. Store the widgets by pointer:

   ```
   class MyClass : ... {
     QList<QPushButton *> m_buttons; // performs the same as QVector, has <<
     ...
   };

   for(int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
       m_buttons << new QPushButton(QString::number(i),this));
       // you'll be likely adding the buttons to a layout:
       layout().addWidget(m_buttons.back());
   }
   ```
2. or, store the widgets by value in a container that doesn't need to copy them:

   ```
   // C++11
   class MyClass : ... {
     std::list<QPushButton> m_buttons;
     ...
   };

   for(int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
       m_buttons.emplace_back(QString::number(i),this));
       // you'll be likely adding the buttons to a layout:
       layout().addWidget(&m_buttons.back());
   }
   ```